# Заголовок Set-Cookie не работает

Tags: cookie

[image: Скрин ошибки]

Отправляю с фронта http://localhost:3000/login на бек http://localhost:4000/graphql запрос и получаю ответ с заголовком Set-Cookie, который не срабатывает, выводит ошибку на скрине:

> Файл cookie заблокирован потому что его путь не в полной мере соответствует пути запроса URL, или его супердиректории.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему на бекенде:

```
export const sendRefreshToken = (req: Request ,res: Response, token: string) => {
  res.cookie('jid', token, { httpOnly: true, path: "/refresh_token" })
  console.log(req.cookies)
}
```

Заменил path: "/refresh_token" на path: "/graphql"